# Sort images in natural order?

Tags: php

This is my block of PHP.

```
<?php
```

I know that this is where the array is defined.

```
$string =array();
$dir = opendir($filePaththumb);
while ($file = readdir($dir)) {
    if (eregi("\.png",$file) || eregi("\.jpg",$file) || eregi("\.gif",$file) ) {
    $string[] = $file;
    }
}
```

I assume I should use natsort() before the code continues beyond this point.

```
echo "<b><font size='$font_size'>".$gallery_name."</font></b><br>";
$loop = "0";
while (sizeof($string) != 0){
    $img = array_pop($string);
```

Can I use natsort() here?

```
    echo "<center><a href='$filePath$img' download='$filePath$img' target='$target_thumb'><img src='$filePaththumb$img' border='0' width='100%'/><BR><IMG src='img/download.png'></a><BR><BR><BR><BR></center>";
    $loop = $loop + 1;
    if ($loop == $loop_end) {
        echo "<br>";
        $loop = "0";
    }
}

?>
```

How can I sort images in natural order?

Comment: So  in other words: You want to grab all images with one of these extensions: `.jpg, .png or .gif` from one folder, sort them natural and then display them?

Comment: So does this code works for you: http://pastebin.com/GRh3Aieq (Just adjust the path in `glob()` for you e.g. `your/path/*.*` )?

Comment: Hi I already resolved the need for my code by adding natsort($string); then additionally reverse the order with array_reverse($string); Thank you so much for your time and consideration!

Comment: But your code is **DEPRECATED**. It is highly not recommended to use these functions! So maybe you want to take a look if my code works

Comment: Thanks for your information. I will give your code snippet a try. I greatly appreciate your valuable contribution!

Answer (score -1, accepted):

after you have created your $string[] array you can now sort it.

It will be sorted *in place* i.e. you don't have to assign a result to another variable, the [natsort()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.natsort.php) function will return true or false (on failure).

```
while ($file = readdir($dir)) {
    if (eregi("\.png",$file) || eregi("\.jpg",$file) || eregi("\.gif",$file) ) {
        $string[] = $file;
    }
}
//print_r($string);
natsort($string);
//print_r($string);

// then display them in order;
foreach ($string as $img){
    echo "<img ...";
    ...
}
```

Comment: Thats what I needed, with your help to make the connection between natsort(); to natsort($string); Thank you for your contribution!

Answer (score 0):

Thanks everyone for you input! Your suggestions helped me greatly!

```
<?php

$string =array();
$dir = opendir($filePaththumb);
while ($file = readdir($dir)) {
    if (eregi("\.png",$file) || eregi("\.jpg",$file) || eregi("\.gif",$file) ) {
    $string[] = $file;
```

After the Array has been filled with .jpg/.gif/.png files, I used

`natsort($string);` to arrange the image files in the $string array in **Natural Order**

I also used `array_reverse($string);` to arrange the order of the image files from filename of greatest Natural Order value to descending Natural Order of value.

```
    }
}

echo "<b><font size='$font_size'>".$gallery_name."</font></b><br>";
$loop = "0";
while (sizeof($string) != 0){
    $img = array_pop($string);    
    echo "<center><a href='$filePath$img' download='$filePath$img' target='$target_thumb'><img src='$filePaththumb$img' border='0' width='100%'/><BR><IMG src='img/download.png'></a><BR><BR><BR><BR></center>";
    $loop = $loop + 1;
    if ($loop == $loop_end) {
        echo "<br>";
        $loop = "0";
    }
}

?>
```

Thanks again everyone!